# How to create mongo network access using gcp terraform

Tags: mongodb, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have created mongo database deployment (M0 cluster) on gcp using terraform. Even I can able to create user below is my code

```
resource "mongodbatlas_cluster" "cluster-test" {
  project_id              = "xxxx"
  name                    = "terraform-cluster"
  # Provider Settings "block"
  provider_name = "TENANT"
  provider_region_name = "CENTRAL_US"
  backing_provider_name = "GCP"
  provider_instance_size_name = "M0"
}

resource "mongodbatlas_database_user" "test" {
  username           = "test"
  password           = "abcqvx768"
  project_id         = "xxxx"
  auth_database_name = "admin"

  roles {
     role_name     = "readWriteAnyDatabase"
     database_name = "admin"
  }
}
```

Now I am trying create network access with ip address (0.0.0.0/0) I am not getting exact resource to create network access.

DB deployment created on GCP. How can I create network access with ip address (0.0.0.0/0) using terraform ?

Comment: What do you mean by `I am trying create network access with ip address (0.0.0.0/0) `? You can't create that address actually, what you could rather do is to whitelist that interface so that your mongo cluster accepts inbound connections from all n/w interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you would like to whitelist `0.0.0.0/0` interface so that your atlas cluster could access connections from all n/w interfaces.

If that's the case I think you could use the resource available [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mongodb/mongodbatlas/latest/docs/resources/project_ip_access_list)

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "test" {
  project_id = "xxxx"
  cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
  comment    = "whitelisting 0.0.0.0/0 for all inbound connections"
}
```

Just to highlight, `0.0.0.0/0` let's your mongo atlast cluster to listen to all inbound connections which is recommended when you have a firewall in between blocking inbound traffic from internet.